# reading structure within a structure from a file

Tags: c, structure

Below is the structure defined.

```
typedef struct{
    int a;
    char b;
}X;
typedef struct{
    X m;
    int c;
    char d;
}B;
B n,q;
n.m.a = 12;
n.m.b = 'a';
n.c = 13;
n.d = 'b';
```

I do a fwrite of the following structure in a file. File is opened as below.

```
fp = fopen("D://tests//t11test.txt","wb");
fwrite(&n, sizeof(B), 1, fp);
```

The fwrite is successful and I checked the contents of the file corresponding to fp.
But when I do a fread on the same file after closing and reopening the file, I am not able to read the contents of the sub-structure m. The fread is

```
fp = fopen("D://tests//t11test.txt","rb");
fread(&q, sizeof(B), 1,fp);
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: what do you mean by "not able to read"?

Comment: I'm going to guess you've re-opened the file with a mode that clobbered the contents of the original file. Can you post a reproducer program?

Comment: @ Karoly   the values **int c** and **char d** are read properly. The **members of substructure X** are not properly read.                @sarnold  I am writing into the file in "wb" mode and reopening it in "rb" to read the structure. Actually I have two programs. one writing the structure into the file and another reading from it.

Comment: Can you post the opening and closing code for `fp`?

Comment: same platform, same machine, same compiler?

Comment: Note that the [comments will only ever notify one @person](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work), and there can't be any space between the `@` and their name.

Comment: .. and please [edit] the post, code in comments is unreadable.

Comment: @Karoly the values int c and char d are read properly. The members of substructure X are not properly read.

Comment: @hmjd please find the code you asked for in the edited post

Comment: Can you post a small compilable program that produces the problem? I, at least, cannot see what the problem is from the posted snippets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see what the problem is, but, FWIW, this worked:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <assert.h>

typedef struct{ int a; char b; }X;
typedef struct{ X m; int c; char d; }B;

void print_B(B* a_b)
{
    printf("{ { %d, %c }, %d, %c }",
           a_b->m.a,
           a_b->m.b,
           a_b->c,
           a_b->d);
}

int main()
{
    /* Write structure. */
    {
        FILE* fp;
        B n;
        n.m.a = 12;
        n.m.b = 'a';
        n.c = 13;
        n.d = 'b';
        fp = fopen("x.dat", "wb");
        assert(0 != fp);
        if (1 != fwrite(&n, sizeof(B), 1, fp))
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to fwrite(): %s\n", strerror(errno));
            return 1;
        }
        fclose(fp);

        printf("wrote: ");
        print_B(&n);
        printf("\n");
    }

    /* Read structure. */
    {
        FILE* fp;
        B q;
        fp = fopen("x.dat", "rb");
        assert(0 != fp);
        if (1 != fread(&q, sizeof(B), 1, fp))
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to fread(): %s\n", strerror(errno));
            return 1;
        }
        fclose(fp);

        printf("read : ");
        print_B(&q);
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
wrote: { { 12, a }, 13, b }
read : { { 12, a }, 13, b }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Its working.. I will let u know the problem in mine.

Comment: No problem, am interested to find out what the issue was.

Answer (score 1):

I think you messed up something else, this works:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct{
    int a;
    char b;
} X;
typedef struct{
    X m;
    int c;
    char d;
} B;

int main() {
    FILE *fd;
    B n, q;

    n.m.a = 12;
    n.m.b = 'a';
    n.c = 13;
    n.d = 'b';

    if((fd = fopen("test.dat", "wb")) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(-1);
    }

    fwrite(&n, sizeof(n), 1, fd);
    fclose(fd);

    if((fd = fopen("test.dat", "rb")) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(-1);
    }

    fread(&q, sizeof(q), 1, fd);
    fclose(fd);

    printf(
        "n.m.a: %d, q.m.a: %d; n.m.b: %c, q.m.b: %c; n.c: %d, q.c: %d; n.d: %c, q.d: %c\n",
        n.m.a, q.m.a, n.m.b, q.m.b, n.c, q.c, n.d, q.d
    );

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
n.m.a: 12, q.m.a: 12; n.m.b: a, q.m.b: a; n.c: 13, q.c: 13; n.d: b, q.d: b
```